# What exactly constitutes a "read" for the purposes of Firebase's daily quotas?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm grabbing some data stored in a Firestore instance:

```
const someData = firestore
  .collection("my-collection")
  .get()
  .then(res => res.docs.map(
    doc => doc.data()
  ))
);
```

There are probably around 3.5K objects being returned from an unfiltered call.

I've hit my daily reads quota quite quickly. Does it count each object as a read? It's not particularly clear to me from reading the docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore: How are "reads" calculated for the quota?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433612/firestore-how-are-reads-calculated-for-the-quota)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `my-collection` contains 3500 documents, then your code is indeed reading 3500 documents. Such unfiltered collection reads are (as you've found) a good way to quickly burn through the free quota of document reads.